# present continuous or going to in that case

Tags: present-continuous, future-time, future-tense

I made an order through the net to reserve a record then in the comment place I wrote "I m not going to cancel this order  as I  did last time with the previous one" would it be possible to write" I am not cancelling it as I  did last time with the previous one".

Which form is the best in this case ?

I think the going to is better but as I am hundred per cent sure of not cancelling but  it is not an arrangment so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are affirming that something will (or indeed won't) happen in the future, you need to use a future form. Thus, "I am not going to", or "I won't" are what you want.

The futurate - the use of the present to express things about the future - is about things that are planned or expected, in some objective way. Not for making assertions, promises, and so on.

Comment: you said that present continuous was not for making assertions, promises and so on What about that  4-reasons-why-im-not-buying-my-girlfriend-a-christmas-present is it because we are very far from christmas that the authour used the present continuous          https://chrisreining.com/4-reasons-why-im-not-buying-my-girlfriend-a-christmas-present/